# how to generate high dimensional/spherical dataset in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

As a part of my project I need to generate high dimensional non linear dataset / spherical dataset...I am using Matlab to generate it...I have tried using randn,surf and plot3 functions ..I referred

http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/numbers-placed-randomly-within-volume-of-sphere.html

I got the output but I dont have any clear idea....Can anyone help with this  or suggest  how to generate the dataset mentioned .. like any function?.Also I would like to view the dataset like by using **plot** or something.....Thanx in advance...

Comment: how would you like to view high-dimensional points on a 2D screen?

Comment: @Shai I hope u have gone through the above link......Plz help.......

Comment: This might be useful. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136314/what-is-a-good-method-to-find-random-points-on-the-n-sphere-when-n-is-large

Comment: How high-dimensional are we talking? The link you give shows for a 3d sphere. For 4d, you could use color to indicate the 4th dimension. With any higher dimension, you will need to project into lower dimensions to display the result. Building on what Shai said, viewing high-dimensional points on a 2d screen is not straight forward.